# Savon returning XML as string, not hash

Tags: ruby, xml, savon

I am trying to parse a SOAP response using Savon. The response is XML but is being returned as one long string. If I use #to_hash the entire XML object is still a string, now stored in

```
hash[:response][:return]
```

which means it is still a huge unusable mess.

My code looks like

```
response = soapClient.request(:get_sites_user_can_access) do
  soap.body = { :sessionid  => session[:login_response][:login_return],
                :eid        => user }
end

rep = response.to_hash

pp rep[:get_sites_user_can_access_response][:get_sites_user_can_access_return]
```

What step am I missing to get useful information out of the response? Note: Unfortunately I can't post the XML response because of the info it contains, but it looks like an entire XML document stored as a string. It's class is **Nori::StringWithAttributes**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the desired results but parsing the Nori string(?) using [this documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/nori/frames). This seems like a less than ideal method, but I realized the last element is an array of hashes. So it's hash, of hashes, with an *array of hashes*. Anyway, here is what worked for me. Advice on how to make this less ugly and clunky would be appreciated.

```
response = soapClient.request(:get_sites_user_can_access) do
  soap.body = { :sessionid  => session[:login_response][:login_return],
                :eid        => user }
end

rep = response.to_hash[:get_sites_user_can_access_response][:get_sites_user_can_access_return]

hrep = Nori.parse(rep)

hrep[:list][:item].each { |item| pp item[:site_id] }
```