# similar gem like savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, savon

i want to give request and get xml response so i'm using savon gem

i am facing problem with savon gem.

i tried version 3 and 2.2

with version 3 i face this problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331827/savon-gem-not-getting-xml-response

with version 2.2 i face error unable to authenticate account

```
response = client.call(:get_models, message: {username: "xxx", secret: "xxx"})
```

followed savon doc  version 2

how can i solve this or suggest any similar gem to savon

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used Savon on several scenarios. I started with other gems (to connect to web services via SOAP), but I ended up moving to Savon. Before selecting another one, please bear in mind [the way Savon responds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079148/savon-returning-xml-as-string-not-hash).

There are other options you can find in [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/). One of them is [HANDSOAP](http://rubygems.org/gems/handsoap). The useful search will lead you to many others you can choose from depending on your specific needs.

Now I remember having started with [soap4r](https://github.com/felipec/soap4r), whose newest version you can find in GitHub.

Hope that helps,

Comment: currently i use version 3 savon, my problem is my example_body contains {:ModelsRequest=>{}}, which should be different something like  {:DivisionsRequest=>{:accountInfo=>{:_number=>"string", :_secret=>"string", :_country=>"string", :_language=>"string", :_behalfOf=>"string"}, :_modelYear=>"int"}}

In soap UI this modelrequest has

 <urn:ModelsRequest>
       <urn:accountInfo number="xxx" secret="yyy" country="ll" language="en" behalfOf="abc"/>
       <urn:modelYear>2013</urn:modelYear>
       <urn:divisionId>1</urn:divisionId>
    </urn:ModelsRequest>

Comment: Please try to use code in this example to make Savon produce pretty JSon notation instead of XML (https://gist.github.com/henrik/1621655)